# When activity goes to background adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(), does not work

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, adapter

In my app the pdf is downloaded on clicking the thumbnial and a [progress indicator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRFer.png) shows the downloaded progress, when the downloaded is completed a broadcast is fired from downloaded class and in main activity broadcast receiver is registered and adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); acts. and the progress indicator goes invisible which is my requirement but 
My problem is this when the main activity goes to background and downloaded is completed the progress indicator does not go [invisible.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhDwx.png) when user go back to the activity

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver=new BroadcastReceiver() 
{
@Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     setContentView(R.layout.gridview);
    new DownloadJSON().execute();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(receiver,new IntentFilter("com.download.complete"));
}

  @Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
```

//on completion of downloading pdf, broadcast is fired
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pls modify your onResume() method

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    if (adapter !=null) {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    registerReceiver(receiver,new IntentFilter("com.download.complete"));
    super.onResume();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You unregister the receiver in the onStop() method. Whenever the activity goes in background you don't have a listening receiver. Hence, notifyDataSetChanged() is not called and your action is not performed.

Comment: thanks for answer but whats the possible solution in my scenario

Comment: use http://stackoverflow.com/a/13824306/3932131 the above accepted answer will cause a memory leak.